Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "get", соответствующие списку аргументов. C++
Ошибка E0304. Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "get", соответствующие списку аргументов. Язык C++.
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    tuple<int, double, string> myTuple(10, 3.14, "Hello");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tuple_size<decltype(myTuple)>::value; ++i) 
    {
        cout << "Element at index " << i << ": " << get<i>(myTuple) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

В 9 строке. get<'i>(MyTuple). В чём причина и как можно исправить?

При инстанцировании шаблона get<i> передаваемый параметр шаблона i должен быть константой времени компиляции.

@user7860670 А что можно сделать, чтобы программа заработала?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply
